# How do you oil a turning kitchen faucet?

Tags: kitchens, faucet, kitchen-sink

I have a kitchen faucet which squeaks more and more. Is it possible to put some oil somewhere to prevent that? Or does it require replacement?

[image]

Comment: There should be a screw under the white cap/button.  You would need a lube safe for rubber/plastic.  Might need repair/replacement of some parts if the lube does not work.  Do remember to turn off the water first.

Answer (score 1):

There are likely rubber O-rings in the faucet that need to be replaced. Over time they flat-spot from the weight of the faucet, as well as wear from abrasion on turning the faucet. This causes metal-to-metal contact (<sub>*squeak*</sub>), and also water leaks. Some O-ring kits come with appropriate lubricant, others may require heat-resistant rubber- and food-safe lube such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000DZFUPC). Check the manufacturer's manual for O-ring size, or take the old O-rings to a hardware store to match.

To access the faucet O-rings, remove the handle (see the manufacturer's manual, but likely either the plastic plug in the handle pops out and there is a screw beneath, or there's an Allen-head set-screw beneath the handle).

Trying to squirt lubricant into the faucet will just make a mess and possibly destroy the remaining O-rings.